# MySQL combining ID to get relation?

Tags: mysql

Table - friends

```
    friend_id     | friend_one    | friend_two   | role 
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1:    44               34              34          me
|2:    45               35              35          me
|3:    46               35              34          fri
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need to count, who is following and who's the follower.. that's pretty much it, I've gotten some answers below but mostly just giving me static numbers but thank you so far for the help, it's given me a place to start.
FRIEND_ONE = 34 ( in table users 34 = their uid the same for 35 and so on )

---

I got this answer before, but it just constantly returns 0 or three for one of these two.

```
select friend_one, count(*) as count
from friends
where friend_one != friend_two 
group by friend_one;

if you want the count for a specific user, do this:

select count(*) as count
from friends
where friend_one != friend_two 
and friend_one = $uid
```

Comment: I don't use MySQL a lot but shouldn't the comparison be the SQL standard of <> instead of != ? Give that a try.

Comment: @PeterJ, thank you for replying either way, I'm not too great with MySQL just really starting out.. do you have a small example that I may go by?

Comment: That's the only problem I can see, so it should just be a matter of changing != to <>

Comment: @PeterJ, yes still doesn't seem to work.. still gives a constant 3. Here is what I'm trying.. http://pastebin.com/QA7jq09V but thank you for the help! I'll keep trying. :/

Comment: Update your question with output, what you want for this input data. And add some more input data like say 7 to 10 rows

Comment: Your SQL is working fine... So, I suppose the DB data or the connection is the problem there. Check some rows of your data to make sure you're expecting a different result, then check your connection, maybe you're looking into different DBs.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out, I needed to select from role as I have here. 

$following = mysql_query("SELECT role FROM friends WHERE friend_one <> friend_two AND friend_one ='$uid'"); returns how many users I'm following.